# PowerApps - How to Edit a Form from a Gallery list result in one screen

Tags: sql, powerapps

In One screen, I have a gallery list with a button along each rows. Upon hitting the button it will display the details in a form. This form should be editable. Is it possible to do it?

My source is a SQL table.

Here's my code

Form:

```
  Item Property
  Gallery2.Selected
```

Edit button: OnSelect

```
 EditForm(Form1);Navigate(Form1, ScreenTransition.None)
```

Thanks for the usual help.

Answer (score 1):

For use case I used D365 as database and Account Table as data.
In first image you will see Acccount name and phone number and so on.

[image]

Now as you wished when clicked on arrow it shall show data of that particular record but in edit mode. Now in 2nd image you will get data in edit mode.

[image]

How do you achive this? Below code will help achive this.

```
EditForm(EditForm1);Navigate(EditScreen1, ScreenTransition.None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes for editable.

I have used Azure SQL database.

**Pre:**

1. Spin up the Azure SQL database ( Free of cost up to some limit)
2. Create a table with some data

**In Powerapps:**
Assuming once you have created connection to Azure SQL database

1. Then insert > Edit form.

[image]

2. Add the SQL Data connection > select the fields
3. Add a button > in the screen > change the forumula to SubmitForm 
   [image]

The following is the most imp bit.

**Note : Edit Text field will not appear if the table doesn’t have Primary key assigned**

Once the record is edited. You can send the `Success Notification` using formulas. Sample below 
To Notify Success:

> Notify("Data Successfully
>   Updated",Success);SubmitForm(Form1);Navigate(HomeScreen,ScreenTransition.Cover)

For Clarity

[image]

Hope it helps